# Ruby on Rails active record/relation problems with has_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

I have two models: Community and Financial.  Community has many Financials.  I'm creating a page that's got community information, along with the most recent financials.  My problem is this: I'm having trouble isolating the active record for the most recent financial.

My controller code looks like this:

```
@community=Community.find(params[:id])
@financial=Financial.where(params[:id => :community_id]).maximum("year")
```

When I run the code, all I get back is a fixnum with the year, not a full array of the financial information.

I've been struggling with this all day, and I'm guessing that the answer is really simple...  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What kind of syntax do you think `params[:id => :community_id]` is? What is the actual column you're trying to query by, and what is the actual value you're trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`@financial=@community.financials.order("year desc").limit(1)`

I suggest having a look at [Active Reord Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: That is still a completely nonsensical thing to do. `:id => :community_id`??

Comment: Right. That was stupid. Corrected my answer. Thanks for pointing out. :)